# Spring Autowired object is always Null

Tags: java, spring, maven, java-8, spring-data

```
package plantSiteMinder.user.impl;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import plantSiteMinder.dao.UserDAO;
import plantSiteMinder.model.User;
import plantSiteMinder.user.UserAuthenticator;
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserAuthenticatorImpl implements UserAuthenticator {
   @Autowired
   private UserDAO userDAO;
   public List<User> findAllUsers() {
       return userDAO.findAllUsers();
   }
}
```

============================Spring.xml==================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
<!-- <tx:annotation-driven /> -->
<bean id="userDAO" class="plantSiteMinder.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl" />
<bean id="userAuth"    
class="plantSiteMinder.user.impl.UserAuthenticatorImpl"/>
<!--    <context:component-scan base-package="plantSiteMinder.dao.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="plantSiteMinder.user.impl" /> -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poc_data" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

=======================Main Class=======================

```
package plantSiteMinder.plantSiteMinder;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import plantSiteMinder.model.User;
import plantSiteMinder.user.impl.UserAuthenticatorImpl;
public class App 
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring.xml");

       UserAuthenticatorImpl userManager = (UserAuthenticatorImpl)   
       ctx.getBean("userAuth");
       List<User> list = userManager.findAllUsers();
       System.out.println("User count: " + list.size());
   }
```

}

UserDAO is always null, how to resolve this not able to find the issue.

=========================User DAO Impl===========================

```
package plantSiteMinder.dao.impl;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import plantSiteMinder.dao.UserDAO;
import plantSiteMinder.model.User;
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;
  public List<User> findAllUsers() {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
    cq.select(root);
    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
  }
}
```

=======================pom.xml========================

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>plantSiteMinder</groupId>
<artifactId>plantSiteMinder</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>plantSiteMinder</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> I am using Java 8 for this project

Comment: You are using XML configuration and auto wiring is disable for that by default. You need to either add `<context:annotation-config />` to switch annotation based configuration on or add `<context:component-scan />` and automatically detect your beans instead of explicitly define them in xml.

Comment: going `<context:annotation-config>` way results in this Error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;`

Comment: going '<context:component-scan />' way results in `BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\mayank.jalotra\workspace\plantSiteMinder\target\cl‌​asses\plantSiteMinde‌​r\dao\impl\UserDAOIm‌​pl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataRead‌​ingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class`

Comment: You are mixing jars of different spring version...

Comment: which one ?.. have added pom.xml

Comment: Make sure that eclipse has the right dependencies and the tyou haven't manually added anything to your eclipse build path (it looks like that now).

Comment: No adding everything via pom.xml, only jdk1.8 i have added in project buildpath by default

Comment: Not according to the exception. That only occurs if you have an old `spring-asm` or mixing `spring-core` version of the actual spring version you are using. You might want to try cleaning things...

Comment: have checked the dependency hierarchy, maven loads multiple dependencies of same jar but there is no such jar with different versions, that may create any conflicts, i agree that its something related to jars, but what it could be is the issue, that was why i edited and added pom.xml as well

Comment: Checking your dependency hierarchy will have no result. Eclipse is pulling in old dependencies mixing things etc. There is old stuff on your class path when you run your application. Run from the command line and see what happens... Also it is not about the same jar it is about jars from different versions of spring i.e. spring-core 4.2 and spring-context 3.2 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Xml config always overrides the annotation config.

One of the solutions would be to remove

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="plantSiteMinder.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl" />
<bean id="userAuth"    
class="plantSiteMinder.user.impl.UserAuthenticatorImpl"/>
```

from xml config and uncomment those lines:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="plantSiteMinder.user.impl" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

You have to remember though that you would have to @Autowire the SessionFactory in your DAo.

Comment: adding component scan gives another error, because of which i removed those, here it is :                                           `BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\mayank.jalotra\workspace\plantSiteMinder\target\classes\plantSiteMinder\dao\impl\UserDAOImpl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class`

Comment: have added UserDAOImpl

Comment: ok, make sure you remove those service and dao beans from xml and put <context:component-scan base-package="plantSiteMinder.user.impl,plantSiteMinder.dao.impl" />

Comment: doing that gives other error of BeanDefinationStoreException : `.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;`

Comment: `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied when using `<context:component-scan />` so you can remove that line when using that.

Comment: tried removing that...comes back to first error `BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\mayank.jalotra\workspace\plantSiteMinder\target\cl‌​asses\plantSiteMinde‌​r\dao\impl\UserDAOIm‌​pl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataRead‌​ingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class`